# How to update the contents of one cell based on the contents inputted inside another cell?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I want a cell to automatically update when the contents in another cell are changed so that the data in both the cells fit a function. For example I have some data in B2 and some other data in B3, I want there to be a kind of restrain of B2+B3 = 29. Suppose that B2 has a data of value x and B3 has a data of value y,so if I change B1 from say x to x+7, then the data in B2 should go from y to y-7.

Comment: In cell B2 you can use =29-$B1-$B3. But if you want both cell B2 and B1 to be dependent, you'd have to use VBA to get there. In that case you need to tag VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this constraint easily if you only need to input into `B2` and never manually write into `B3`:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |
| 2 |  | `20` |  |
| 3 |  | `=29-B2` |  |

If you need to manually enter values into both B2 and B3 you could set up a validating function:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |
| 2 |  | `20` |  |
| 3 |  | `9` |  |
| 4 |  | `=If(B2+B3=29,"","B2 and B3 must sum to 29!")` |  |

You could also set up a conditional formatting rule to highlight invalid selections.

To automatically enter the other value to keep the total 29, you'd need VBA.

Comment: what is a VBA? I do not know much about this I am only doing this to help a friend. If u can elaborate it would be very helpful thanks.

Comment: VBA = Visual Basic for Applications, a programming language built into MS Office products.